# Delete a single row from RecyclerView Room DB

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, android-room

So I have a recyclerView and when a user clicks on LikeButton, the item/row is saved to a Room DB "favorite_table" and to a UserFavorite activity.

When the user clicks on the selected LikeButton again, I want to remove the row from "favorite_table" on my DB and favorite activity. Using **mAppRepository.deleteRow(favoriteModel);** **doesn't delete the row/item clicked. How can I delete the row/item when the LikedButton is clicked?** The adapter for the recyclerView:

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove from your database and from adapter at same time to see the result realtime, assuming your room database is set correctly. Do this in this part of your onBindViewHolder:

```
            if (mLocalStorage.isLessonFavorited(lessonsModel.getKey_id())) {
                mLocalStorage.unFavoriteLesson(lessonsModel.getKey_id());
                mAppRepository.deleteRow(favoriteModel);
                //remove from database
                mAppRepository.deleteRow(favoriteModelList.get(positon));
                //remove from adapter
                favoriteModelList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


                holder.fav_status.setLiked(false);
                StyleableToast.makeText(v.getContext(), removeFromText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        R.style.toastStyles).show();

            }
```